# Creating pixel effects in SDL 2.0

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm working with SDL 2.0 right now and I want to be able to create effects for images that I draw on screen and I'd like to be able to string these together. The basic idea is to support a list of effects that will alter the SDL_Texture or Surface.

it would look like

```
SDL_Texture* effectFunction(unsigned int ms_delta, SDL_Texture* texture_to_alter){
    //some code to edit our image
    return edited_image;
}

class GameObject{
    vector<EffectFunctionPoint* > m_effectList; //a list of effects to apply when rendering
    void draw(){
         for(effect in m_effectList){
            this.texutre = effect(ms_delta, this.texture);
         }
        //actually draw texture here
    }
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Would it be to slow to keep accessing textures/surfaces?

Comment: Look up [Shaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language) and [Post-Processing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Post-Processing)! ... You should also read [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview)!

Comment: Ok, but stringing together shared effects seems significantly harder. Also that would require moving rendering from SDL functions to my own. Though you're right... that would be the way to go for systems with graphics cards.

Comment: If you wanted to do CPU based image effects on pixels/non-OpenGL textures, then you shouldn't have added the [tag:OpenGL] tag!

Comment: True enough, I'll edit this. Though I'll need to learn OpenGL anyway. Sorry about that.